# scrollTo after a href with jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a html web page, and the main problem for now is that I do not know how to scroll to a section of page after clicking a new link. What I did was I used the scrollTop jQuery method :

```
$("#klienti2").click(function(){
    $('.parallax').animate({ scrollTop: windowHeight }, 'slow');
});
```

and it scrolled the amount of windowHeight from the top of the screen. I choose this method over using navigation with ids, because there is no content at the spot where I need to scroll.

So what I am looking for now is to do the same thing after redirecting to this page from different page. What I tried was :

```
$("#audio2").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "prew2.html";
    $('.parallax').animate({ scrollTop: windowHeight*2.6 }, 'slow');
});
```

but now it just redirects to that page without scrolling. Any ideas why? I thought that, fallowing the code, it should href to the location and then animate to the specified location, but it seems to ignore the animate.

Comment: HTML is stateless. Once you change href, anything following is disregarded as the code is unloaded. You need to pass something to the receiving page (e.g. a query string parameter on prew2.html) and react to that instead from inside `prew2.html`.

Comment: Use a url parameter and then handle that in jQuery

Comment: Redirecting the page will stop any current running Javascript.

Comment: I agree with @TrueBlueAussie, you need something in URL of the page to indicate if it needs to scroll to the position of html element.

Comment: Apologies for the typo. `indexOf` has a capital `O` below :)

Answer (score 5):

From comment: HTML is stateless. Once you change href, anything following is disregarded as the code is unloaded. You need to pass something to the receiving page (e.g. a query string parameter on `prew2.html`) and react to that instead *from inside `prew2.html`*.

The receiving page needs to know whether, or not, to scroll to the intended location. That decision whether to scroll, or not, is made by the caller.

The obvious method is to pass a parameter in the query string. As this code acts just like a bookmark URL, you might as well use a bookmark URL for the task and check for a specific bookmark value:

In your first page the link code would be something like:

```
$("#audio2").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "prew2.html#doitnow";
});
```

Of course if that is just a normal anchor, this would do the same:

```
<a id="audio2" href="prew2.html#doitnow">Click me</a>
```

In the receiving page the code would be like this:

```
$(function(){   // Shortcut for DOM ready handler
    if (location.href.indexOf("#doitnow") >=0 ){
        $('.parallax').animate({ scrollTop: windowHeight*2.6 }, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, and yes, I can use link tag instead of JavaScript now. But with Moz FF I'm getting an error : `"location.href.indexof is not a function"`
I did as you said: ceated a href to "prew2.html#doitnow" and in JS file in my document ready function: `if (location.href.indexof("#doitnow") >=0 ){
  $('.parallax').animate({ scrollTop: windowHeight*2.6 }, 'slow');
 }`

Comment: @Oskars: Typo: It is a capital `O` in `indexOf`

Comment: It works great, but I'm getting worried about >=0 part. Cant it make bugs in random situations? Like when loading that page it automatically scrolls to that part, when not asked?

Comment: The `>= 0` just means that the *string exists or not*. It is a boolean switch, so you will not get random bugs if that query string param is not an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

Your script tells the Browser to open a new Url on click

```
window.location.href = "prew2.html";
```

Now the Browser navigates to this address, stopping all actual scripts and building a new DOM.

```
$('.parallax').animate({ scrollTop: windowHeight*2.6 }, 'slow');
```

This code is never reached and will never execute.

Comment: You think this is a solution? Nope.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Actually, it does answer the question ***Any ideas why?***

Comment: You asked why it didnt work, thats why. 
For a solution follow @TrueBlueAussie and pass a parameter and check for it with a regex or something like that.

Comment: @LcSalazar: How does this solve the problem outlined? This only answers the most basic part of the question and does not solve the actual problem outlined. It certainly does not appear to be worth *5 upvotes* (it is more of a comment) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I agree it's not a solution and shouldn't be upvoted... I just contested the state "This does not answer the question", when it actually does, since the question didn't ask for a solution... It was more of a criticism to the question than a complement to the answer. (I didn't upvote it, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Place outside of the original click statement and on the page that is being navigated to.

```
if(window.location.href === "prew2.html"){
     $('.parallax').animate({ scrollTop: windowHeight*2.6 }, 'slow');     
}
```

A simple if statement will check and then apply changes when you reach that url

Comment: You used assignment instead of compare!

Comment: Also, need to remind that this statement is to be placed outside the `click` event handler

Comment: Also, you also need to explain that this code has to go in *both pages* in order to do anything :)

Comment: Of course if the URL is the only thing you check this code is pointless (it just animates the scroll *always* in page `prev2.html`)! You need to conditionally scroll to that point based on a decision from another page... Who upvoted this? :P